# How can I get all taxonomies include post category, tag,...?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, categories, offset, custom-wordpress-pages

How can i get all taxonomies include post taxonimies( category, tag,..). In this code i only get taxonomies in Listing! help me

```
$args = array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false 
  ); 
  $output = 'names'; 
  $operator = 'and'; 
  $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, $output, $operator ); 
  $options = get_option( 'accn_plugin_options' );
    echo "<select id='new_settings_plugin_list_taxonomy' name='accn_plugin_options[list]'>";
      echo "<option values=''>-- Please chose Taxonomy --</option>";
      foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
          ?>
              <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($taxonomy) ?>" <?php selected( $options['list'], $taxonomy); ?>><?php echo esc_html__( $taxonomy, 'list' ) ?></option>
          <?php 
      }
    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Please check this I think this is helps you https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L193

Answer (score 0):

use " or " operator to get default post_type like 'post'

```
$args = array(
  'public'   => true,
  '_builtin' => false
 );  
 
 $output = 'names'; 
 $operator = 'or';
```

if you want to get builtin taxonomies like nav_menu or link_category
assign '_builtin' to true

```
$args = array(
  'public'   => true,
  '_builtin' => true
 );  
 
 $output = 'names'; 
 $operator = 'or';
```